# Как объединить два разных массивав один?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива

Первый массив

```
    array
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'bonus' => string '5.625' (length=5)
          'date' => string '2016-01' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'bonus' => string '2.5' (length=3)
          'date' => string '2016-02' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'bonus' => string '2.5' (length=3)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '8' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'bonus' => string '10.625' (length=6)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => null
      4 => 
        array (size=4)
          'bonus' => string '22.125' (length=6)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => null
          'month' => null
```

Второй массив

```
    array 
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '5' (length=1)
          'date' => string '2016-07' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '7' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '6' (length=1)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '8' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '21' (length=2)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => null
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '21' (length=2)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => null
          'month' => null
```

Необходимо объединить массивы, что бы получилось следующим образом

```
    array
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '0' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '5.625' (length=5)
          'date' => string '2016-01' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '0' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '2.5' (length=3)
          'date' => string '2016-02' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '5' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '0' (length=3)
          'date' => string '2016-07' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '7' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '6' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '2.5' (length=3)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => string '8' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '21' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '10.625' (length=6)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
          'month' => null
      5 => 
        array (size=4)
          'amount' => string '21' (length=1)
          'bonus' => string '22.125' (length=6)
          'date' => string '2016-08' (length=7)
          'year' => null
          'month' => null
```

Размеры массивов постоянно разные. Всю голову уже сломал, не могу понять как их объединить таким образом.

Comment: И на чем основан критерий объединения? и если различаются данные других полей, но критерий объединения совпадает, то что делать?

Comment: Вы пишите, что у вас критерий объединения поле date, но в результате у вас 3 одинаковых массива с одинаковым полем ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что SO - это не фриланс.

Comment: Причем тут фриланс? Ты где увидел, что я прошу что бы за меня сделали?

Answer (score 1):

если вам необходимо слить оба массива в один нужно использовать php функцию `array_merge`
Вот тут есть документация - [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: array_merge не подходит, она сливает не так как нужно

Comment: @jemxx что конкретно не так?

Comment: array_replace_recursive наверное

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходим функция array_map. В callback функции сливайте оба вложенных массива в один. Подробнее тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php